# Passing a Mongo ObjectId in a URL and querying that ID with Node/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having a lot of trouble passing in an objectId as my URL parameter. I know that the ObjectId in MongoDB is a hex value, and that I need to do some conversions, but I'm getting errors with every method I use to do this.

Currently, the error that I'm getting states, "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters."

```js
var mongo   = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


 app.get('/characters/:id', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.params.id);
   var collection = db.collection('Character');
   _id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
 });
```

The request I'm passing is:

```
address/characters/:565dffa7463e4c60b1166f43
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Note the colon. Try your code without passing it.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That makes complete sense now that I think of it. I'll give this a try when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 1):

the request should be:
    address/characters/565dffa7463e4c60b1166f43

then the req.params.id becomes 565dffa7463e4c60b1166f43.